# How to call Gradle build task from Gulp build running in Node.js environment

Tags: java, node.js, gradle, build, gulp

I have added Gradle to my project to manages Java dependencies, it basically fetches all the jars from maven and then runs a copy task to copy all the jars to a destination folder.

I run the Gradle from the command line at the project root folder:
gradle build   //fetch all the jars
gradle copyJarsToDest   //a custom Gradle task to copy all the runtime environment dependencies

Now I am asked to integrate my Gradle task into an existing Gulp Build task. The Gulp Build is running in Node.js environment and uses Babel for the latest JavaScript features.  The Gulp Build pulls the code from Git repository,  compiles the JavaScript and Java code, then put them into jars that can be deployed to our servers. When I start to look into how to call my Gradle task from Gulp, I only see the various posts about calling Gulp from Gradle, nothing on calling Gradle from Gulp.

Any ideas on how to call Gradle within Gulp? I am new to Gulp, I don't know if there is a way for me to ask Gulp to execute command lines "gradle build" and "gradle copyJarstoDest"? Many thanks.

Comment: Gulp is just Javascript, so just check how to run a command from Javascript. There won't be a plugin for Gulp, because Gulp plugins are just about processing files (as Vinyl objects).

Comment: Thank you Lukas. I solved the issue as you suggested. I used the "exec" inside a promise, worked like a charm.